# Pause Menu Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when ever i press e nothing pops up and i am not to sure why
it also has no errors what does not show up i had set it as escape before and nothing
how would i get this to work or is there another work around to this situation

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            } else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume ()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }

    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quiting...");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Start call with Update. Because start is called only one frame

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            } else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
```